# Programmatically change the startup form on application launch?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, startup

Can I programmatically change the startup form on application launch in VB.Net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can!

In your Project Properties, set Startup Object to Sub Main, and make sure that there's a Public Sub Main method somewhere in your application.  A separate startup class may be a good idea:

`Public Class myStartupClass`

```
''' <summary>
''' This is the method that will be run when the application loads, 
''' because Project Properties, Startup Object is set to SubMain
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>
''' </remarks>
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Shared Sub Main()

    'The form that we will end up showing
    Dim formToShow As System.Windows.Forms.Form = Nothing

    'The determiner as to which form to show
    Dim myMood As String = "Happy"

    'Choose the appropriate form
    Select Case myMood
        Case "Happy"
            formToShow = New Form1
        Case Else
            formToShow = New Form2
    End Select

    'Show the form, and keep it open until it's explicitly closed.
    formToShow.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

`End Class`

Comment: Be aware, for this option you must switch a *Windows Form Application* (if you have it, which would be in most cases in this scenario) into *Console Application*. That has a *lot* of consequences. This might be difficult and unfeasible action with existing application.

Answer (score 4):

In a "Windows Forms Application", created under VB 2010 Express, you can do the following in ApplicationEvents.vb:

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

       'Select the form of your choice
       My.Application.MainForm = Any_Form_You_like

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I use which effectively starts a form like a normal an application entry point.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim value As String = Trim(Environment.CommandLine)
    Dim f As Form
    Select Case value
        Case "a"
            f = New frmTextEdit
        Case "b"
            f = New frmListDialog
        Case "c"
            f = New frmSuggestion
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("Unsupported startup form option")
    End Select
    Application.Run(f)
End Sub
```

Comment: The same I wrote to the other answer of this type. Be aware, for this option you must switch a *Windows Form Application* (if you have it, which would be in most cases in this scenario) into *Console Application*. That has a *lot* of consequences. This might be difficult and unfeasible action with existing application.

Comment: It is used this way for a console app or a forms app set to sub main.
I have yet to find any consequences with this approach so far, the documentation basically indicates "Application.Run(form)" is how a forms based app is created and they even reference this to be the correct way to do it... `You should use the Run(Form) overload to start an application with a main form, so that the application terminates when the main form is closed` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It's true, that I didn't test it with this particular code. I played with settings around and set it using GUI, including `Sub Main()` variant. VS threw an error and explicitly told me I am running a *Windows Forms Application* and that I have to switch to *Console Application*. I also run into another issues with suppresing the main form, so I ended up on just hiding it and showing another form. It might be sensible just in my scenario, though.

Answer (score 0):

The right method is change MainForm of project.

1. Open ApplicationsEvents.vb
2. At ApplicationStart.vb use:

   ```
       Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
       Dim formToShow As System.Windows.Forms.Form = Nothing
       Dim AM_PM as String = "AM"
       Select Case 
           Case "AM"
               Me.MainForm = frmBefore
           Case "PM"
               Me.MainForm = frmAfter
       End Select
       MainForm.Show()
   End Sub
   ```

That's is.