# VS2010 VB.NET Winforms select startup form programmatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm really struggling to find out how to dynamically load a form when starting a VB.NET winforms application in VS2010.

Looking at existing answers such as this: [Programmatically change the startup form on application launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271836/programmatically-change-the-startup-form-on-application-launch)

Has not helped. I do not have a main method (that I can see) in my winforms project and when I go into the project properties I can only select a start-up form. But I have one of two forms to display on start-up depending on the user accessing the application.

I tried to set a loading form up which, in it's load event would call .Show() on the correct loading form after it had determined it and then the loading form would close itself down, but doing this led to both forms being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found in the properties a button to generate the MyApplication class in which I can access the startup event.

Answer (score 2):

Below are steps for VS2010 VB.NET Winforms select startup form programmatically.
1 : Go to My project from Solution Explorer
2 : Click on Application Tab--->Uncheck Enable application Framework
3 : Then Inside module create Sub like this

```
 Public Sub Main()
        MsgBox("called Main") 'This is testing
        Login.Show() 'Set your start up form here
    End Sub
```

4 : Again My Project--->Application Tab--->Startup Object--->Sub Main
5 : Thats it, It will give you message box and will show Login form.

Hope It will help you.

Thanks
Mahesh

Comment: In Main, possibly call Application.EnableVisualStyles()

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an MDI form.  When it loads you can determine which child form to display.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Sub Main` is the way I have done this forever but for some reason, MS has decided to make the norm, difficult.  To use the `Sub Main` way, create a "Module" if you dont already have one. Put this code in there:

```
Sub Main()
  Stop
End Sub
```

Now, in your project properties, assuming your are doing a standard WinForms application, on the "Application" tab, uncheck the "Enable Application Framework". This will allow you to see (and select) "Sub Main" in the "Startup Object" drop-down.